# how to use Dojo to show/hide programmaticaly generated combo boxes by clicking radio buttons?

Tags: combobox, dojo

When I run my application, both combo boxes show. How to show one and hide the other one when clicking radio buttons?

I stored the state and region in a static json file and use xhrGet to get them. 
i want to use dojo combo box for auto-complete.

```js
var cboState;
var cboRegion;

dojo.xhrGet({
                url: "../client/stemapp/widgets/samplewidgets/myProject/common.json",
                handleAs: "json",
                load: function (result) {
                    require([
                        "dojo/store/Memory",
                        "dijit/form/ComboBox",
                        "dojo/domReady!"
                    ], function (Memory, ComboBox) {
                        var stateStore = new Memory({
                            data: result.states
                        });

                        var regionStore = new Memory({
                            data: result.regions
                        });

                        cboState = new ComboBox({
                            id: "state",
                            name: "state",
                            placeholder: "Select a State",
                            store: stateStore,
                            searchAttr: "name",
                            autocomplete: true
                        }, "state");

                        cboRegion = new ComboBox({
                            id: "region",
                            name: "region",
                            placeholder: "Select a Region",
                            store: regionStore,
                            searchAttr: "name",
                            autocomplete: true
                        }, "region");

                    });
                }
});

domStyle.set(dom.byId('state'), "display", "block");
domStyle.set(dom.byId('region'), "display", "none");

On(query('.radio'),'change',function(){
    query('.query').forEach(function(divElement){
     domStyle.set(divElement, "display", "none");
    });

    domStyle.set(dom.byId(this.dataset.target), "display", "block");
});
```

```html
<input class="radio" data-target="state" type="radio" name="selection" value="state" > State
<input class="radio" data-target="region" type="radio" name="selection" value="region" > Region
<div id="state" class="query"></div>
<div id="region" class="query"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I let you deal with the creation of the combobox, but here is the code you were trying to write.
it is a simple and basic use of `dojo/on`

```js
require([
  'dojo/dom',
  'dojo/dom-construct',
  'dojo/dom-class',
  'dojo/query',
  'dojo/on',
  'dojo/store/Memory',
  'dijit/form/ComboBox',
  'dojo/domReady!'
], function(dom, domConstruct, domClass, query, on, Memory, ComboBox) {
  var stateStore = new Memory({
    data: [{
      name: "Alabama",
      id: "AL"
    }, {
      name: "Alaska",
      id: "AK"
    }, {
      name: "American Samoa",
      id: "AS"
    }, {
      name: "Arizona",
      id: "AZ"
    }, {
      name: "Arkansas",
      id: "AR"
    }, {
      name: "Armed Forces Europe",
      id: "AE"
    }]
  });

  var regionStore = new Memory({
    data: [{
      name: "North Central",
      id: "NC"
    }, {
      name: "South West",
      id: "SW"
    }]
  });

  var comboState = new ComboBox({
    id: "stateSelect",
    name: "state",
    store: stateStore,
    searchAttr: "name"
  });
  comboState.placeAt("state");
  comboState.startup();
  
  
  var comboRegion = new ComboBox({
    id: "regionSelect",
    name: "region",
    store: regionStore,
    searchAttr: "name"
  });
  comboRegion.placeAt("region");
  comboRegion.startup();


  on(query('.radio'), 'change', function(event) {
    query('.query').forEach(function(divElement) {
      domClass.add(divElement, 'hidden');
    });
    domClass.remove(dom.byId(event.target.value), 'hidden');
  });

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">


<input class="radio" data-target="state" checked="true" type="radio" name="selection" value="state">State
<input class="radio" data-target="region" type="radio" name="selection" value="region">Region
<div id="state" class="query"></div>
<div id="region" class="query hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. I tried your codes, and the two combo boxes still show up. The two divs are set to hidden, but two combo boxes show up. That seems strange to me.  any thoughts?

Comment: @AlexW. I've edited the answer. In your orginal code, you create the combo like this: ```new ComboBox({/*...*/},"region").startup();```. Using this syntax, dojo will REPLACE the ```div region``` instead of putting the combo inside it. I replaced by ```placeAt```. Also, as a good practice, you should add remove class instead of adding removing inline styles : ```display:block``` is not the opposite of ```display:none```.... If you REALLY want to use inline style, you'd better do : ```domStyle.set(divElement, "display", "");``` instead of ```domStyle.set(divElement, "display", "block");```